# How to extract an HTTP URL using vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract the **first** URL `https://example.com/ccm/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.Attachment/72306` from the following string using vanilla Javascript.

```js
var str = '<a href="https://example.com/ccm/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.Attachment/72306" data-cke-rtc-autolink="true" data-cke-rtc-autolink-text="Anhang 72306" data-cke-rtc-autolink-url="/ccm/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.Attachment/72306" class="jazz-ui-ResourceLink" id="jazz_ui_ResourceLink_23" widgetid="jazz_ui_ResourceLink_23">Anhang 72306</a>';

var pattern = /^http(.*?)(")/g;
var match = pattern.exec(str);
alert(match);
```

What would be a good search command or regex? Please note that there is a second URL-like string later in the string that I don't want to extract.

Comment: DOM is vanilla javascript and should let you select the link's `href` attribute much more easily than regex would ; do you mind such a solution? `document.getElementById("jazz_ui_ResourceLink_23").href`

Comment: can you show the URL like string next to this

Comment: @Aaron Thank you but I wasn't able to identify the element by a unique ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not regex but here is a solution :

```js
var str = '<a href="https://example.com/ccm/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.Attachment/72306" data-cke-rtc-autolink="true" data-cke-rtc-autolink-text="Anhang 72306" data-cke-rtc-autolink-url="/ccm/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.Attachment/72306" class="jazz-ui-ResourceLink" id="jazz_ui_ResourceLink_23" widgetid="jazz_ui_ResourceLink_23">Anhang 72306</a>';

var url = str.split('href=')[1].substring(1).split('"')[0];
alert(url);
```

I first split the string on "href=", then I take the second part of the split, remove the first quote and split again on quote